# Chatbot handoff from Messenger to Zendesk

Tags: botframework, crm, messenger, zendesk

I am developing a customer service chatbot, using Azure's Bot Framework in .NET, using the the Messenger channel. I wanted to know if anyone knows what the best way to handle the handoff to a human on Zendesk (which my platform already uses as its CRM platform). I'm not looking for when to do the handoff, but how to manage what happens next.

What I would love to be able to do would be that so when handoff is needed, a ticket on Zendesk would be created, sending for example a file (the transcript of the conversation so far). Then the agent would be able to solve the customer's problem in that ticket, having a conversation with him, having the bot sending messages back and forth between zendesk and messenger.

I don't know if this has been done before, or if it's at all possible. And I'm free to other solutions to the problem of handling this kind of handoff, without having to create a separate "chat" for the customer service agents to use, like it's explained on the azure documentation.

Comment: Hi @Edhelvar, I'm looking into this to see what options might be available.

Comment: For now I'm using Messenger's own Handover, redirecting to the page's inbox. Only found about it yesterday. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your patience while I researched this. I found this resource that I believe will meet your needs. This functionality is built off of the Bot Framework utilizing .NET (it's also available for Nodejs). There are two available methods to connect a client to an agent.

The first (which should apply to you) aggregates different channels into one allowing an agent to pickup in the same channel where the bot handed off. The second opens a new channel when an agent joins the conversation.

[Intermediator Bot](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample)

I was able to spin up a bot using this and confirmed the bot was listening for outside traffic.

Hope this helps.

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I'm about to try is this:

- Bot conversation ends.
- Bot service calls an Azure Function, passing the conversation content.
- The Azure Function integrates with Trello API, creating an entry on a Kanban board.

So, instead of Trello as I want to do, you can make a call to the [Zendesk API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction).

I'm writing a few articles about developing Azure bots. The next two actually are dealing with these very things. You can find out more [here](https://developerlabs.co). sign up if you'd like to get notified over the next week or so when the new tutorials are online.

Hope that helps!
Tim